# Sum of elements from two data.table with different length by matching row

Tags: r, data.table

I have two `data.table` of different length - `dt1` and `dt2`:

```
> dt1
   Column_1 Column_2
1:        A        3
2:        B        2
3:        C        5
4:        D        1
5:        E        4


> dt2
   Column_1 Column_2
1:        A        2
2:        C        5
3:        D        4
```

I want to create another `data.table` with the sum of `Column_2` by `Column_1`. The desired output should be:

```
> dt3
   Column_1 Column_2
1:        A        5
2:        B        2
3:        C       10
4:        D        5
5:        E        4
```

I have tried using this method:

```
dt3 = setDT(dt1)[Column_1 %in% dt1$Column_1, .(Column_2 = dt1[, "Column_2"] + dt2[, "Column_2"]), by = Column_1]
```

but due to the different length of the two `data.table` I get the error message:

```
Error in Ops.data.frame(dt1[, "Column_2"], dt2[, "Column_2"]) : 
  ‘+’ only defined for equally-sized data frames
```

Comment: The general approach would be to join the two tables by `Column_1` before creating a column that is the sum of the two columns `Column_2`

Comment: I think it's a union/rbind operation not a join. `rbind()` your two tables and then sum - `rbind(dt1, dt2)[, .(Column_2 = sum(Column_2)), by=Column_1]` or something similar (untested)

Comment: @thelatemail This works! Does this works for subtraction as well?

Comment: If you make the second table negative values, it should: `rbind(dt1, dt2[, .(Column_1, Column_2 = -Column_2)] )[, .(Column_2 = sum(Column_2)), by=Column_1]`

Answer (score 1):

What was stated in the comments (please credit @tic-tic-choc)
the code could actually look like this:

```
library(dplyr)

dt3 <- dt1 %>%
  full_join(dt2, by = "Column_1", suffix = c("", "_dt2")) %>%
  mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~ ifelse(is.na(.x), 0, .x)),
         Column_2 = Column_2 + Column_2_dt2) %>%
  select(-ends_with("_dt2"))
```

Why I use a full_join? - Perhaps you have data in one frame that isn't present in the other one and vice versa...

You could use left_join, right_join or inner_join as well - just carefully read their documentation.

Why did i do the `mutate(accross(where(is.numeric), ~ code)))`thing?

Becaus when you do 5 + NA you get NA - therefor all NAs in numeric columns have been replaced by 0.0.